# FindController is Not Working with Monaco Editor

Tags: vscode-extensions, monaco-editor, monaco-languageserver, react-monaco-editor

In my custom IDE, I am using monaco editor.

We have added a lnaguge server using monaco-language client.

We used @monaco-editor/react package to integarte with react.

After integration when I click on CTRL + F find popup is not shown and warning is shown as
[image]

When I Click on ALT + W, I am getting below error.
[image]
Can someone help me
When I removed loader.config({monaco), lanaguge client is working suggestions are getting fine is working but find is not working. But when I remove Find is working but suggestions are missing

I am expecting both language clinet and find controller should work as expected

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround for this problem. In the monaco-editor package, you need to find the RawContextKey class (in this file `\esm\vs\platform\contextkey\common\contextkey.js`), remove the inheritance copy and paste  content of constructor and copy the methods from the parent class.